# Can't launch service with net.tcp binding error 10049

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp

I have a problem with launching a WCF service using net.tcp endpoints. I'm getting an 10049 error.

My `app.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour0"
                 name="Tinkl.Server.Services.Authentication.AuthenticationService">
            <endpoint name="httpEndpoint"  
                address="reg"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                contract="Tinkl.Server.Services.Authentication.IRegistrationService" />
           <endpoint name="httpEndpoint" 
               address="auth"
               binding="basicHttpBinding"
               contract="Tinkl.Server.Services.Authentication.IAuthorizationService" />
           <!--
           <endpoint name="tcpEndpoint" 
               address="net.tcp://78.26.210.203:50050/reg"
               binding="netTcpBinding"
               contract="Tinkl.Server.Services.Authentication.IRegistrationService" />
           <endpoint name="tcpEndpoint"
               address="net.tcp://78.26.210.203:50051/auth"
               binding="netTcpBinding"
               contract="Tinkl.Server.Services.Authentication.IAuthorizationService" />
               -->
           <endpoint name="mexEndpoint"
               address="mex"
               binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
               contract="IMetadataExchange" />
           <host>
               <baseAddresses>
                   <add baseAddress="http://78.26.210.203:50076/" />
               </baseAddresses>
           </host>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour0">
                <!--<serviceMetadata />-->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

There are 2 endpoints with `netTcpBinding` and 2 same exact with `basicHttpBinding`.

The problem appears when I'm trying to use `netTcpBinding` endpoints, I'm getting an error, but with `basicHttpBinding` it works fine...

[image]

I'm hosting the WCF service in a console application.

Program code

```
ServiceHost authenticationHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(AuthenticationService));
authenticationHost.Open();

Console.WriteLine("close <ENTER>\n");

Console.ReadLine();
authenticationHost.Close();
```

Maybe someone faced a similar problem?

If needed, I will give all the necessary additional information

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are getting an error on a tcp listener according to the exception.  Listeners should not be listening to an IP address.  You should be listening to an endpoint IP.Any.

Comment: @jdweng, Could you please give an example?

Comment: See webpage : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181993/how-to-create-a-wcf-that-listens-to-tcp-requests-over-web.  The program code is probably starting the listener.  for socket code examples see following : You can use any class that inherits the socket like TCPListener instead of a socket : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace lines

```
net.tcp://78.26.210.203:50050/reg
```

with

```
net.tcp://localhost:50050/reg
```

And the same for `/auth` endpoint.