# Socket Exception 10049 in TCP connection

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, connection

I'm trying to connect an external device with an Ethernet cable using a TCP protocol. I know which are the IP address and the port of my device. Here the code I'm using:

```
public IPAddress DEFAULT_SERVER = IPAddress.Parse("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");
public int DEFAULT_PORT = yyyyy;
public IPEndPoint DEFAULT_IP_END_POINT = new IPEndPoint(DEFAULT_SERVER, DEFAULT_PORT);

...

public void TcpConnect()
{  
   try 
   {
        serverSocket = new Socket(DEFAULT_IP_END_POINT.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, 
                                  ProtocolType.Tcp);
        serverSocket.Bind(DEFAULT_IP_END_POINT); 
        serverSocket.Listen();
        serverSocket.Accept();
   }
   catch(SocketException se)
   {
        MessageBox.Show(se.ToString());
   }
}
```

I receive the socket exception 10049 at the *socket binding* line. Any suggestion?

Comment: You cannot bind to external/remote IP addresses, it is the remote machine the one that would bind/open that port. You may want to check on some networking stuff (port forwarding)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't launch service with net.tcp binding error 10049](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39932200/cant-launch-service-with-net-tcp-binding-error-10049)

Comment: I'm sorry I feel a bit confused. I tried the same code, modifying only the IPEndpoint definition

`public IPEndPoint DEFAULT_IP_END_POINT = new IPEndPoint(IpAddress.Any, DEFAULT_PORT);`

In this case, the exception thrown is 10051. Could you clarify what you mean with you cannot bind to a remote IP addresses? I need to connect with a machine that has a specific IP and port.

Comment: Binding and listening means you are the one opening a port to others to connect. A quick google search on `socket error 10051` gives me the description `Error 10051 happens because the other network is unreachable, usually because there is a problem with the router or modem on the computer attempting the connection`.

Comment: I solved the issue simply using the Connect method intead of the three calls to Bind, Listen and Accept:


`serverSocket.Connect(DEFAULT_IP_END_POINT);`


Anyway thank you for your comment